# How to check an int array value for null?

Tags: java

So I basically have an integer array and I need to check if a value in it is null, the "==" doesn't work since:
"The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null"
switching to an Object array doesn't work since I can't add integer values to it.

so this is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
int [] x = new int [5];
y()

void y() {
  if (x[0] == null) {
    println("value is null");
  } else if (x[0] != null) {
      println("value is not null");
    }
  }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: An element of an `int[]` array can **not** be `null`. Only reference types can have a value of `null`. Maybe you're confusing `null` and zero `0` ?

Comment: Also note that the syntax for your `else if` is incorrect.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, when i tried to check for 0 i got a NullPointException so if i didn't put anything in it what is?

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah i saw that, it's fixed now

Comment: Have you tried using the int wrapper class Integer ?

Comment: *"when i tried to check for 0 i got a NullPointException"* - have a careful at the code that gives you NPE. In the message on the console, there would be a reference to the line that causes the exception. Post the updated code and exception stack-trace if the issue would be unclear.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that exactly demonstrates the problem you're having. Include the stack trace of the error thrown by your example.

Answer (score 2):

`new int[size]` will create an array of that size of all `0`. It **cannot** contains nulls.

If you did want to store `null`, then do as the error says, create `new Integer[size]`, which will default to all `null` references in an array of that size.

> can't add integer values to it

Why not?

```
x[0] = new Integer(1);
x[0] = 1; // or, auto-boxed
```

> when i tried to check for 0 i got a NullPointException

Sounds unrelated, and perhaps you are using a wrong reference to an `x` array which was not initialized.

Depending on your use-case `OptionalInt[]` may be better, although initializing an array of any non-primitive will always start as all `null`s, so then you'd have to check `.isPresent()` **and** `== null`